# How to show content in div based on json data

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, ng-show, ng-hide

I am working on an AngularJs app it has ng-view with routes. In the object i have an option of showOnHome, I would like to show a product if the value is set to true and hide if set to false.

In the nodejs server:

```
app.get('/cameras/:id', function(req, res){
var cameraId = parseInt(req.params.id);
var data = {};
for (var i=0, len=cameras.length; i<len; i++){
    if(cameras[i].id === cameraId){
        data = cameras[i];
        break;
    }
}
res.json(data);
});

app.get('/cameras', function(req, res){
res.json(cameras);
});

var cameras = [
                      {
                        "id": 1,
                        "title": "BVO473N 850TVL IR Dome Camera",
                        "features": [
                          "2.0 Megapixel CMOS image sensor",
                          "2 megapixel high definition image quality",
                          "Minimum illumination of 0.1 Lux at F1.2 and 0 Lux with IR On",
                          "42 units of IR LEDs with an IR range of up to 30m",
                          "Supports dual streaming",
                          "Supports mobile surveillance via iOS, Android, Windows Mobile, BlackBerry",
                          "Supports plug and play - no port forwarding or networking knowledge required",
                          "Ingress Protection rating of IP66",
                          "Power Supply: DC 12V"
                        ],
                        "picture": "images/cam-look.png",
                        "showOnHome": true,
                      },
                      ];


<div class="row" ng-repeat="cam in cameras">
            <hr ng-if="!$first" />
            <div ng-show="cam.showOnHome">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">
                    <img ng-src="{{cam.picture}}" alt="Description"     class="img-responsive" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">
                    <p class="lead">{{ cam.title }}</p>
                    <ul class="specs list-unstyled">
                        <li ng-repeat="feature in cam.features">{{ feature     }}</li>
                    </ul>
                    <strong class="more"><a href="#/product/{{ cam.id     }}">Learn More</a></strong>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: So, what's your issue?

Comment: I am unable to show/hide item based on the value of showOnHome

Answer (score 1):

Try to bubble up your `ngShow`/`ngIf`:

```
<div class="row" ng-if="cam.showOnHome" ng-repeat="cam in cameras">
```

If you put inside, outer div still rendered.

Also, you initialize `var cameras` (for debug purpose?).
It should be `$scope.cameras` to access it in your controller template.

Comment: tried the <ngif> this is not working. Its in factory do i still need to use $scope?

Comment: How can I help you, if I can't to see your factory code? Anyway, template uses own `$scope` variables. You should assign it to access. Write `{{cameras}}` to template to see you correct assign it.